# $A=B^2+2B$, what can I say about $\det B$?

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let $A, B$ are $n\times n$ matrices which satisfy :
$$A=B^2+2B$$

Given $\det A=2$, then what can I say about $\det B$?

---

First try :

$$A=B(B+2I), \quad \det A=\det B\det (B+2I)$$

But there is no information about $\det(B+2I)$.

Second try :

Add identity matrix both side :

$$A+I=B^2+2B+I \quad\Rightarrow\quad A+I=(B+I)^2$$

I tried rewrite RHS with using $I=I^2, A=(B+I)^2-I^2$

but this returns same result, still got stuck.

What can I say about $\det B$ with this condition? or is $\det B$ indeterminate?

Comment: If $A,B\in M_n(\Bbb Z)$, then $\det(A)=2$ implies that $\det(B)=\pm 1$ or $\det(B)=\pm 2$, because $2=1\cdot 2$ or $2=(-1)\cdot (-2)$ for integers.

Comment: We don't need $A=B^2+2B$. We only need that $2=\det(B)\cdot \det(B+2I)$. So find all $B$ with this condition (what is the domain for the entries?)

Comment: @DietrichBurde There was no specific condition about entries, so I assumed all entries are real.

Comment: So you should say: "Find all  values of $\det(B)$ for $B\in M_n(\Bbb R)$ with $\det(B)\det(B+2I)=2$". Start with $B=\lambda I$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks! I tried with your hint and it depends on $\lambda$, So I can not say anything in general sense. But how did you think assume $B=\lambda I$?. Is this well known method to approach these problems?

Comment: If $P$ is an invertible matrix such that $P^{-1}BP$ is triangular, then $P^{-1}(B^2+2B)P=P^{-1}BPP^{-1}(B+2)P=P^{-1}BP(P^{-1}BP+2)$ will also be a product of two triangular matrices $P^{-1}BP$ and $P^{-1}BP+2$. For example, you could take $P$, possibly complex, such that $P^{-1}BP$ is the Jordan normal form of $B$. Incidentally $P^{-1}BP+2$ will also be in Jordan normal form. This allows you to describe all solutions.